# Preventing Gigabit Loss due to printers

Tags: networking, printer, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

HOW CAN I MAINTAIN Gigabit Ethernet integrity given this situation:

****** What I have to work with: ******

AC-router w/4 port gigabit 
N-600 router w/4 port gigabit
Switch w/8 port gigabit
All PCs have gigabit NICs
4-port POE injector at gigabit

---

**(all wiring = Cat 6)**

---

******Problem =**
Printer @ 10/100 (built-in)
Printer @ 10/100 (built-in)
Scanner @ 10/100 (built-in)
Printer @ 10/100 (built-in)****

---

What device (not setting up a PC) or configuration would I have to incorporate to get gigabit going given those devices?

WILD SHOT: IS THERE SUCH A THING AS A SWITCH THAT CAN ACCOMMODATE THIS?

THANK YOU ALL

Comment: Are the switch gigabit only? Every switch I have worked with is a a 10/100/1000 and will auto-negotiate the correct speed. If that does not work, I can configure the switch and force a speed on a specific port. What kind of switch are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it's clear what you're asking about. I think you were trying to make lists of network devices, but as you can see, everything came out on one line. The editor window has a live preview in which you can see what your post will look like, and you can also read the [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help). Please remove ALL CAPS as well and clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

"Maintain Gigabit Integrity" sounds like a goal set by someone who does not understand how networks actually work. Connecting a 100Mbit printer to a Gigbit network does not limit anything but the connection to the printer to 100Mbit.

Pretty much any Gigabit copper switch will happily connect everything and auto-negotiate the fastest speed each item can handle.

The 10/100 devices will run at 100Mbit. Anything that can actually run gigabit will run gigabit.

If you're asking for a magical means to make those 10/100 devices run gigabit, there isn't one. Nor is there any need for one.